# Proof that Hadamard matrices of order $4k+2$ don't exist

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-matrices

It's known that Hadamard matrices can only exist for orders $1$, $2$ and $4k$. It's easy to show that there are no Hadamard matrices of order $2k+1$. But what is the proof that there are no Hadamard matrices of order $4k+2$?

Comment: What you say in your first sentence is correct. But note that it is [an open question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Hadamard_conjecture) whether Hadamard matrices exist for _all_ integers of the form $4k$. (You probably know this, but casual readers may not.) According to that link, the smallest value of $4k$ for which no Hadamard matrix is known is $668$.

Comment: Presumably you mean $4k + 2$ for $k \geq 1$

Comment: @TonyK Yeah, I was reading exactly that, and that's why I got this question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume the Hadamard matrix has $\ge3$ rows.

Consider the top row. You may as well assume it is all ones. (otherwise change the signs
of various columns). Then row two and row three each
consist of $n/2$ ones and $n/2$ minus ones.
So $n$ is even. As row $2$ and row $3$ are orthogonal, then they agree in $n/2$
entries. So if row $2$ and row $3$ both have ones in $k$ columns, then in $n/2-k$
columns, row $2$ has a one and row $3$ a $-1$ and so in $k$ columns, row $2$
and row $3$ both have $-1$s. So they agree in $2k$ entries: $2k=n/2$ and $n$
is a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 2):

The following is taken from this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem):

> Any two rows of an $n\times n$ Hadamard matrix are orthogonal. For a $\{1, −1\}$ matrix, it means any two rows differ in exactly half of the entries, which is impossible when $n$ is an odd number. When $n \equiv 2\pmod 4$, two rows that are both orthogonal to a third row cannot be orthogonal to each other. Together, these statements imply that an $n \times n$ Hadamard matrix can exist only if $n = 1, 2$, or a multiple of $4$.