# To show that this matrix is a multiple of 4

Tags: matrices, determinant

**8.** Let $n\ge3$. Let $A=((a_{ij}))_{1\le i,j\le n}$ be an $n×n$ matrix such that $a_{ij}\in\{1,-1\}$ for all $1\le i,j\le n$. Suppose that
$$a_{k1}=1\quad \forall1\le k\le n$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^na_{ki}a_{kj}=0\quad\forall i\ne j.$$
Show that $n$ is a multiple of $4$.

Yesterday this question was asked in an examination. I could not solve this problem but intuitively this is correct. A proof is needed.

Comment: It's better the qstns was written.I had provided a picture for better understanding

Comment: Pictures? No! Pictures cannot be read by people who rely on screen readers. And the picture was sideways.

Comment: Okay thanks.. Parcly taxel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof that Hadamard matrices of order $4k+2$ don't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735526/proof-that-hadamard-matrices-of-order-4k2-dont-exist)

Comment: I am unaware of what is a Hadamard matrix

Comment: Can you kindly provide an detailed  answer to this one